# Compilation error when passing variadic args to a template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, bind, variadic-templates

I have the following template method:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void register_scene(const std::string& name, Args&&... args) {
    auto func = std::bind(&T::template create<Window*, Args&...>, std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    _store_scene_factory(name, [=](Window* window) -> SceneBasePtr {
        auto ret = func(window);
        ret->set_name(name);
        return ret;
    });
}
```

Essentially all I need to do is bind the variadic `Args` to `T::create` (which itself is a static variadic template method), but allow populating the first argument (window) separately when it's called.

The above code fails with the following error

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const std::_Bind<std::shared_ptr<{anonymous}::SceneWithArgs> (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, const char*))(smlt::Window*&, const char (&)[4])>) (smlt::Window*&)’
         auto ret = func(window);
                    ~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

When calling the code like this:

```
manager.register_scene<SceneWithArgs>("test", "arg");
```

I don't really understand the error, or how to fix it.

I initially solved this by simply calling create inside the lambda, and this works on GCC 4.9 and above, but I have to remain compatible with GCC 4.8.4 and there's a bug which prevents using variadic args inside a lambda :(

**UPDATE**

OK so adding std::decay (as seen in the comments) didn't fix the problem entirely, the first argument kept deducing to `Window*&&` rather than `Window*`, but actually specifying the type of `func` (e.g. `std::function<SceneBasePtr (Window*)>`) instead of using `auto` made things compile.

I'm not sure why that is though...

Comment: You may want to turn `create<Window*, Args&...>` into `create<Window*, typename std::decay<Args>::type&...>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show the declaration of `create`, but I assume it looks as follows:

```
template <typename... Args>
static SceneBasePtr create(Args&&...);
```

It looks good. You use forwarding references, so that the compiler can deduce the exact types of arguments. As long as the compiler deduces the types, this will work. However...

```
 &T::template create<Window*, Args&...>
```

Here, you instantiate the function template explicitly. That is, the compiler will no longer deduce the types, instead, it will replace the template parameters by the template arguments you provide. What are these template arguments?

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void register_scene(const std::string& name, Args&&... args);
//...
manager.register_scene<SceneWithArgs>("test", "arg");
```

The first one is passed explicitly, it's `Window*`, this one is obvious. Now `Args...` -- `"test"` and `"arg"` are raw string literals, and their corresponding types are `const char[5]` and `const char[4]`, respectively. Then `Args...` (after a deduction process) become `const char(&)[5]` and `const char(&)[4]`. Then what happens now, when you instantiate `create` with these types? You will end up with a declaration as below:

```
static SceneBasePtr create(Window*&&, const char(&)[5], const char(&)[4]);
```

Note that reference collapsing rules turn the first parameter into an r-value reference, while the rest are l-value references.

`std::bind` deduces types as well. However, `std::bind` will want to store the arguments, so that they can be reused later. The problem is that `std::bind` cannot store `const char[5]`. Instead, it will *decay* the type of each argument. This means that each raw string literal will become `const char*`, and will be passed as an l-value argument of this type to the bound function, and this does not match the manually instantiated `create`. A similar problem is with the `window` argument. It is deduced as an l-value, however, the manually instantiated `create` function expects an r-value.

It's best not to explicitly specify template types of a function template. If for some reasons (bug?) you cannot use `args...` inside the lambda, you can generate a proper `create` signature:

```
&T::template create<Window*&, typename std::decay<Args>::type&...>
//                        ~^~          ~~~~~~~~~^
```

To end up with:

```
static SceneBasePtr create(Window*&, const char*&, const char*&);
```